# How to get zebra crossing line count from the image in swift5

Tags: swift, image, image-processing, pixel, swift5

I need to find out zebra crossing line count when i capture from camera.

I have used zebra crossing image and convert into the pixel but i cant able to find the count of zebra crossing line.

I have used objective c function to get pixel from image

```
#define Mask8(x) ( (x) & 0xFF )
#define R(x) ( Mask8(x) )
#define G(x) ( Mask8(x >> 8 ) )
#define B(x) ( Mask8(x >> 16) )
#define A(x) ( Mask8(x >> 24) )
#define RGBAMake(r, g, b, a) ( Mask8(r) | Mask8(g) << 8 | Mask8(b) << 16 | Mask8(a) << 24 )
- (UIImage *)processUsingPixels:(UIImage*)inputImage {
  
  // 1. Get the raw pixels of the image
  UInt32 * inputPixels;
  
  CGImageRef inputCGImage = [inputImage CGImage];
  NSUInteger inputWidth = CGImageGetWidth(inputCGImage);
  NSUInteger inputHeight = CGImageGetHeight(inputCGImage);
  
  CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
  
  NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
  NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
  
  NSUInteger inputBytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * inputWidth;
  
  inputPixels = (UInt32 *)calloc(inputHeight * inputWidth, sizeof(UInt32));
  
  CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(inputPixels, inputWidth, inputHeight,
                                               bitsPerComponent, inputBytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                               kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
  
  CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, inputWidth, inputHeight), inputCGImage);
  
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    
  #define Mask8(x) ( (x) & 0xFF )
  #define R(x) ( Mask8(x) )
  #define G(x) ( Mask8(x >> 8 ) )
  #define B(x) ( Mask8(x >> 16) )
    
    // 2. Iterate and log!
    NSLog(@"Brightness of image:");
    UInt32 * currentPixel = inputPixels;
    for (NSUInteger j = 0; j < inputHeight; j++) {
      for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < inputWidth; i++) {
        UInt32 color = *currentPixel;
        printf("%3.0f ", (R(color)+G(color)+B(color))/3.0);
        currentPixel++;
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
    
    free(inputPixels);
    
  #undef R
  #undef G
  #undef B
    
  return inputImage;
}
```

Reference image :-

[Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6USx4.png)

This is output of pixel :-

[This is output of pixel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bwh5k.png)

I need to find out the count of horizontal line for that i have converted image into pixel.

I really don't know this is a right way to find out the count of lines.

Please tell me if anything is not clear so i can update the question.

Thank you.

Comment: This is an image processing question. That's a rich and complex subject. I suggest looking at a library like OpenCV.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion i will check it. if you have some idea about this please share some references @DuncanC